# Can apiary.io echo back request data?

Tags: apiary.io

If I have an apiary.io API described like this:

```
### Create a User [POST]
+ Request (application/json; charset=utf-8)

        {
            "user_id": 1053,
            "username": "demo@demo.com",
            "email": "demo@demo.com",
            "active": "true"
        }

+ Response 201 (application/json)

        {
            "user_id": 1053,
            "username": "demo@demo.com",
            "email": "demo@demo.com",
            "active": "true"
        }
```

When I call it from my application and pass it data, it will always pass me back the described payload no matter what data I pass in.

Is there a way to get it to echo back the exact data that I passed in instead of the described payload?

Answer (score 0):

According to Apiary docs/examples you can not, only static request-response mocking. Also you could track this [issue](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/58).

If you want to use kind of advanced mocks I would suggest you [wiremock](http://wiremock.org/docs/). It's not so fancy, but way more feature reach. You could run it as a service and update mock mappings at runtime by sending HTTP requests.

Please check [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581520/using-wiremock-can-i-return-a-body-that-is-dependent-on-the-post-request) for your question using wiremock. Related [documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/).